# What happens at the browser level when a max concurrent HTTP request limit is hit?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I know that different browsers have different amounts of concurrent connections they can handle to the same hostname, but what exactly happens to a new request when that limit is hit?

Does it automatically wait and retry again later or is there something I need to do to help this process along?

Specifically, if this is a `XMLHttpRequest` executed via JavaScript and not just some assets being loaded by the browser from markup, could that automatically try again?

I have a client side library that makes multiple API requests and occasionally it tries to send too many too quickly. When this happens, I can see server side API errors, but this doesn't make sense. If the concurrency limit stops requests, then they would have never hit the server, would they?

**Update:** Thanks to @joshstrike and some more testing, I've discovered that my actual problem  was not related to concurrent HTTP request limits in the browser. I am not sure these even apply to JavaScript API calls. I have a race condition in the specific API calls I'm making, which gave an error that I initially misunderstood.

Comment: The browser will simply queue requests beyond a certain limit in some internal queue and process them when an active request ends and a "slot" opens up. It's not about "trying again", the request isn't *rejected*, it'll simply wait until it will be executed. If you're seeing server-side API errors, that means the request has actually been made to the server, so has nothing to do with internal browser limits on outgoing requests…

Comment: But would it also queue an XMLHttpRequest? It's one thing for it to wait a while before an image or style sheet is eventually loaded, I just wasn't sure if the queuing could happen that deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will not retry any request on its own if that request times out on the server (for whatever reason - including if you exceed the API's limits). It's necessary to check the status of each request and handle retrying them in some way that's graceful to the application and the user. For failed requests you can check the status code. However for requests which simply hang for a long time it may be necessary to attach a counter to your request, and "cancel" it after a delay... Then if a result comes back bearing the number of one that has already been canceled, ignore that result if a newer one has already returned. This is what typically happens in a long-polling application that is hitting a server constantly and not knowing whether some pings will return later or never return at all.

Comment: I'm going to have to construct a specific test bed and see if I can capture the error then. It can't be an HTTP error code, since they'd all have to come from a server connection. Ultimately I will just modified the API wrapper library we use to internally queue requests and call them only when the last one has been sent.

Comment: If these are asynchronous calls then I'm not aware of any limit at the browser level. If your calls must be ordered and return in order then you must wait for the  previous one or continue calling and discard it if it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Interesting. Are you suggesting the limit applies to asset loading via HTML tags with a src and not to JavaScript XMLHttpRequests?

Comment: I've edited my post to confirm that I've found my actual problem and that I don't think API requests count towards this API limit (my test ran 500 API requests in rapid succession with no problem). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

When the limit on the Chrome is reached it pauses anymore requests. Once one request has been responded to, the browser sends the next request. On Chrome that limit is six for me.